# How can I replace blocks with air in Minecraft BE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I filled up a house with `light_block` in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) and I need to replace them with `air`. Is there any possible command to do that?

---

<sub>***Note**: I'm not against using a command block if needed. I just need to get rid of them.*</sub>

Comment: Reopen bc the duplicate isnt even the same game.

Comment: @Penguin Well, isn't the answer the same in both versions? I don't see the problem then of leaving this closed and adding `minecraft-bedrock-edition` to the duplicate.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 i suppose, but i reemmber one meta post that said not do that with i think u and dlly in it although I cant find it at the moment. Also neither of the answers will really work in Bedrock. Instead of adding alternate answers that will work in both versions it makes more sense to just have a different question

Comment: @Penguin The `/fill` command has the same syntax in both editions. The accepted answer's command should work.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I realize it is not applicable here, but don't (vote to) close questions based on their answers! (Since the commands here are the exact same, IMHO adding the Bedrock tag to the older question seems like a good alternative, though.)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 but it makes no sense to modify a question so that multiple solutions are allowed. The answers that are already there then don't apply to the question asked, and you have to add alternate answers that shouldn't be needed to be added there in the first place! Why wouldn't it make more sense to have a separate question for the right edition of the game? The accepted answer uses the debug menu which will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `replace` functionality of the `fill` command to accomplish this. Per the [DigMinecraft documentation](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/fill_command.php):

> To replace one type of block in a region with another type of block:
>
> ```
> /fill <from> <to> <tileName> [tileData] replace <replaceTileName> <replaceDataValue>
> ```

As such, the command to replace all `light_block` in a `15x5x15` area with `air` would be:

```
fill ~ ~ ~ ~15 ~5 ~15 air 0 replace light_block
```